# How can I copy & paste, or duplicate, an existing project?

Tags: jenkins, project, hudson, copy-paste

I've got an existing Hudson project that is configured and working.

I need to duplicate the project so that I can have the original and then change the new one so that it points to a different source control.

I don't want to manually recreate the build. How can i "copy & paste" or otherwise duplicate the exiting build configuration, so I can get the new build configuration up and running faster?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Click on "new job" and then select "Copy existing job" at the bottom. Then enter the name of the job you want to copy into the text field.

Comment: "New Job" is at the Jenkins root, aka the Dashboard

Comment: Is It possible to build the clone job in jenkins

Comment: There's also a _Copy project link_ plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29774399/2434565

Comment: you gotta copy/paste the source-job name....and you gotta put a new job name in.  I know : "duh"....but I wasn't putting in a new job name for a few minutes.....

Comment: @Thomas Lötzer how can I copy a job that is not under the **SAME** parent? e.g, I need to copy `../../DIR1/job_x` to `../../DIR2/job_x`?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to copying a job, I sometimes copy parts of the XML file that contains the job configuration. You just paste the copied part into the xml file of the new job and reload the configuration (under *manage hudson*). This is helpful when you change the original job after you created your copy. However, for your use case the copy is the right thing to do.

Comment: The XML file is a config file for each job located on the master under `HUDSON_HOME/jobs/<job name>/config.xml`

Answer (score 1):

When you do new job, you can make the choice to copy it from an existing job. Later alter the settings of the new job.

Comment: hmmm.. my browser did not notify me of a new answer ... hence duplicate