# How do I clone a job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

`Jenkins` has the `Gerrit` Plugin in place so that when we do check-ins to `Gerrit`, `Jenkins` performs a build and if it succeeds, then the modification in `Gerrit` is verified.  If the build fails then it is not.  My understanding is that this is accomplished through jobs set up in `Jenkins`.  We have now created a new branch and I guess I need to clone the existing jobs pointing to the other branch so that this same workflow occurs and builds are performed on every commit.  Can somebody explain how I would clone these jobs? I don't seem to see a way to do it through the UI nor can I even see a way to list the jobs out through the UI.

Comment: You should be able to "Copy Existing Job" as one of the options on the New Job page. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133537/how-can-i-copy-paste-or-duplicate-an-existing-project

Answer (score 218):

To copy an existing job, go to `http://your-jenkins/newJob` and use the "Copy existing job" option.  Enter the name of the existing job - Jenkins will verify whether it exists.

The default tab on the front page of Jenkins should list all existing jobs, but maybe your predecessor deleted the tab.  You can create a new tab listing all jobs from `http://your-jenkins/newView.`

Comment: beware, that while copying existing job, you need to provide the name (not encoded as in url while accessing the job), so if the job name has spaces, they will be preserved. Shortly, put only original *name* of the job, nothing else.

Comment: With the ez-template plugin installed "Copy existing job" applied to a template or to a job using a template creates a new job dependent on the template.  If you actually want an independent copy you can then delete the `Use another job as a template` configuration.

Answer (score 174):

You can clone a job:

1. Click on 'New Item' link
2. Give a new name for your job
3. Select radio button 'Copy existing Item'
4. Give the job name that you want to clone
5. Click 'OK'

Finally, you have your new job, which reflects all features of your cloned one.

Answer (score 141):

#### Jenkins 2.9

1. Jenkins > **New Item**

   [image: Jenkins New Item]
2. **Enter an item name** - E.g. "MY_CLONE"

   [image: Enter an item name]
3. Specify the source (**Copy from**) job > **OK**

   When you start typing the name, the existing values will be found. Notice that this is case sensitive.

   [image: Copy from OK]
4. Click on **Save** if you want to keep the default values.
5. Now both jobs are available in the same location:

   [image: View jobs]

Comment: Pictures are worth a thousand words. Couldn't find the little dropdown for the life of me. Mulțumiri

Answer (score 61):

`New Item`>`Project Name` = `abc` > Instead of `Freestyle job`, select `Copy from job name of already existing jobs`

If you are inside the folder that you want to copy out of the directory then use `../`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `../`

Comment: I wish there would an option not to copy branches and tags that do no exists in new job when I save it, it takes ages to delete them one by one. All I wnat is to just copy job and set different repository.

Answer (score 18):

if you want to copy in same Jenkins but in different subfolders, create new item -> use copy from. new Job will be cloned in same directory. Then use move option to move it in desired directory

Comment: This is what I used. Just copying into the same folder is often not enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

All above answers are good. But if you have created "folders" for your jobs, things are slightly different.

Click on the folder under which you want to create a new job. Then click "New Item" on the left menu. Now your "new job" URL will look like this (assuming you are creating the new job under "my-folder"):

`http://my-jenkins:8080/job/my-folder/newJob`

Under `Enter an item name`, enter your desired new job name.
Then use the `Copy from` text box at the bottom. Enter job path of he source job.

E.g. If your source job is under folder `src-folder` and name of the job is `src-job`, you will have to enter `src-folder/src-job` in "Copy from" box.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am still trying to find a way to copy jobs cross folder structures: Jenkins add the literal "job" for each new item that is a folder, e.g. I have a job at **http://localhost:8080/job/x/job/y/job_1**, where x and y are folders. job_1 is the real job. How can I copy this job to **http://localhost:8080/job/x/job/z/job_1**? I tried all reference to the source job with no luck.

Comment: Go to `localhost:8080/job/x/job/y/job_1`. On that page, you should see `Full project name`. Try using that when you specify the source.

Comment: If you have 2 folders `folder1` and `folder2` at the same level and you want to copy `folder1\job1` to `folder2\job1`, you can create a new item into folder `folder2` and then use `..` to go back in the folder structure and copy `../folder1/job1`.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I had to copy over a job from one jenkins instance to another.

So first I looked under the directory structure of the old Jenkins (the job/directory name; also noted the config.xml)  and then under the directory structure of the new jenkins where I then created a directory with same name/job and copied over the config.xml under this newly created dir.

Then under, "Manage Jenkins", I hit "Reload Configuration from Disk". Thats it.

Comment: thanks for the "Reload Configuration from Disk" tip!

Comment: Yeah, doing like this when I have to bulk copy several items, before "Reloading from Disk" you can also do some required manual magic in CLI such as search/replace some parameters, pieces of text, etc in **config.xml**. Note that the name of the directory where **config.xml** is located is the name of your Job (thus, if unlike Rohit you need to create a new Job, just give it a different name).

Comment: In my opinion, when you have several levels of folders with many jobs inside, this is the best option.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the [Copy project link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+project+link+plugin) plugin.

This will add a link on the left side panel of your project:

[image]

Following screen will ask for the new Job name:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Create a new Item and go to the last you'll find option to copy from existing, just write your current job name and you will have clone of that project to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to copy Jenkins job from subfolder. `copy from` option did not show the suggestion which i was looking for.Without using suggestion copying the job name didn't work.

So if you want to create a job from outer folder, you need to first create the job in subfolder and then move it in different folder where you need to place it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Jobcopy Builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jobcopy+Builder+plugin)

Answer (score 0):

All the answers here are super helpful but miss one very weird bug about Jenkins. After you have edited the new job configurations, sometimes if your zoom level is too high, you may not see the `save` or `apply` button option. The button is present on the page and hidden by your zoom level, you have to zoom out until you see the button at the bottom left of your page.

Strange, I know!